# Using localForage inside service workers in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, service-worker, localforage

I'm trying to to use localForage inside the service worker to store private access tokens.
I don't want to keep the entire localForage file inside my webserver but rather use it from the installed npm library.

I tried using `importScripts("localforage.js")` but it cannot find the library at the desired path. Is there any configuration that I am missing here?